# Auth options in environment

Tags: postman

I have different environments for an api (different servers, dev, staging, live). I can use curly brace placeholders for say the username, but I still need to replace the auth headers on each stored request.

Is it possible to run a post environment script that automatically updates headers or does what ever needs to be done?

*Comment:* I can use the generated header value from the environment, that is something like `Basic blabla` which is then referenced in the requests. Still wondering whether a more elegant way is possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi I think I have a similar setup with my authorization headers.

In postman there is a button "Manage presets" which allows you to set default header values that can be used across different requests.  I've created a parameterized header in the following way:

Key: Authorization, Value = Bearer {{Access_token}}

At the top center there is a section where you can manage variable in your environments.  For each environment I have created the following variable to hold the access token:

Key: Access_token, Value =

Note the value is left blank as it will be set after the authorization response is generated in the next step.

I then use the Test editor because it runs AFTER the response is generated as opposed to the Pre-request Script editor which runs before.  In the Test editor I grab the value of my authentication token with the following script:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Access_token", data.Access_token);
```

Note that I'm setting this variable per environment (not globally) so that I can have separate tokens for each environment (Dev, QA, Staging, Production, etc).

So now the token that I captured can be sent as a header with each subsequent request by Clicking the "Add preset" button and choosing the Authorization preset header I previously defined.

So for my needs the flow goes as follows

1. Request to get access code
2. With response from access code, Reqeust is made to get token
3. Token is saved as an environment variable.
4. On each subsequent call the authorization header is passed as a preset header automatically.

Comment: I have 200+ subrequests. Is there any way to set something like "always use header preset"?

Comment: @KonradGałęzowski I haven't explored that ability personally and don't know of any universal way to accomplish it.  I do know that the pre-request Script (runs before request) and the Tests (runs after the request) editors both allow you run javascript code.  But in both case of setting the header manually or doing it through javascript, you will still have to update each request.